# Which characters are illegal within a git remote name?

Tags: git, git-remote

Which characters are illegal within a git remote name ?

I didn't found it the git documentation.

Comment: For example, to check a branch name, we can use `git check-ref-format <branch-name>` command.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't find anything in the documentation, either. So let's take a look at the source.

When you try to add a remote with an invalid name or rename a remote to an invalid name, you'll get an error message like

> fatal: 'foo@{bar' is not a valid remote name

So let's [search the Git source for *that*](https://github.com/git/git/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22is+not+a+valid+remote+name%22&type=Code).

We see that Git goes about this a bit backwards: It tests ([here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.0/builtin/remote.c#L192) for `add`ing, [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.0/builtin/remote.c#L631) for renaming (`mv`)) whether `refs/heads/test:refs/remotes/<the remote name>/test` is a valid fetch reference, as determined by [`valid_fetch_refspec(<the ref name>)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.0/remote.c#L615), which in turn calls [`parse_refspec_internal(...)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.0/remote.c#L496).

The latter does many checks that will most of the time pass anyway due to the majority of the input being given in our case, but it will also [call `check_refname_format(...)` on the right-hand side](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.0/remote.c#L562) (i.e. the `refs/remotes/<the remote name>/test` part if the [splitting at `:`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.11.0/remote.c#L515) went alright).

I guess this means that the characters and character sequences disallowed for branches and tags are also forbidden for remote short names.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
We can have a remote name with a special characters.

If the **remote name** begins with `-` character, we should precede git command with `--` option.

With the option `--`, we can add, remove, push in a remote name which begin with `-`character. But it didn't work for `git pull`, because git pull is a combination of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

Do you have any idea on how to fix it and make a `git pull` with a remote name which start with `-` character ?

Comment: `--` let to git to separate between command option and the remote name.

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that, nor whether it's possible at all. While `git remote add` doesn't currently disallow such names, maybe it _should_ disallow them?

Comment: Yes, I have created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464862/how-to-pull-from-a-remote-name-which-begin-with-a-dash

Comment: I'd upvote this answer more than once if I could :-) Well, once will have to suffice.

Answer (score 3):

As you and das-g have noted, it's not documented anywhere.  However, remote names normally become embedded within remote-tracking branch names, so all of the constraints enforced by [`git check-ref-format`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html) will generally apply.

There is something relatively minor that is missing from the check-ref-format code, though.  A branch name that consists solely of letters from the set `[a-f]`, possibly mixed with digits, sometimes becomes ambiguous!  For instance, the word `fade` is a perfectly good English-language verb.  However, it's also a valid hexadecimal number ... and all Git objects have a 160-bit SHA-1 hash, usually expressed as a 40-character hexadecimal number like `e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c`.

There is also an "abbreviation length", set via `core.abbrev`, which defaults to 7.  This *is* documented in [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), but what remains undocumented is that there is also a *minimum abbreviation length* that is currently compiled-in at 4 and is not configurable (it's not clear why the source uses a variable when the value is not settable).  You may use an abbreviated form of a hash, as long as it unambiguously selects one particular Git object, so if `master` is that big ugly 40-character hash above, you may express it as just `e05806d`, and Git often will:

```
$ git reflog
e05806d HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from ...
```

Let's note that the word [`cab`](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cab), meaning taxi or taxicab (or an ancient Hebrew measure), also consists solely of letters from the "hexadecimal number" space (so it could be the number 3243, expressed in hexadecimal, just as `faded` might mean 1027565).  However, since `cab` is *below* the minimum abbreviation length of 4, it *will not* be treated as a hexadecimal number, so it makes a good branch name, or remote name.  But `faded` exceeds the minimum abbreviation length.

Should Git happen to create an object whose full 160-bit hash *begins with* the sequence `faded`, the name *faded* will become ambiguous!

Git actually starts trying to interpret object IDs at the minimum value (4), but as it happens, there are two `e058` commits<sup>1</sup> in the Git repository for Git now:

```
$ git show e058
error: short SHA1 e058 is ambiguous.
error: short SHA1 e058 is ambiguous.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'e058': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
$ git rev-list --all | grep '^e058'
e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c
e05881a4577cedca4d7456b3cb1f8bbd6f480df2
$
```

What this means is that a perfectly good word like `fade` may be a valid branch or remote name for some time (because there are no commits whose ID begins with `fade...`).  Once there *is* such a commit, while the name is still a valid branch name in *format*, some Git commands could perhaps treat it as an object ID.  We can test this by creating a branch whose name is the same as this commit-specifier `e0580`:

```
$ git branch e0580 e0580^
$ git show e0580
warning: refname 'e0580' is ambiguous.
commit af09003b2897db76cefdb08ab363ed68f2bb295b
Merge: 58fcd54 b22d748
[snip]
$ git branch -d e0580
Deleted branch e0580 (was af09003).
```

(`af09003` is the commit just before `e0580`, abbreviated to `core.abbrev` length).  Testing shows that branch names are normally preferred here, which is good, since these things don't *become* ambiguous until there's at least one matching commit.

But, this brings us to the one missing check in `git check-ref-format`.  It probably should warn if the name could become ambiguous, and it *definitely* should warn or fail if the name (a) could become ambiguous and (b) is *exactly 40 characters long*.  The reason is that if the name *is* exactly 40 characters long *and* can be interpreted as a SHA-1 hash value, it *is* interpreted as a SHA-1 hash.

In [`sha1_name.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sha1_name.c#L577-L586), around line 580, Git contains a message, and bit of code that prints it out if it encounters one of these 40-character-long reference names.  Curiously, there is no corresponding test in `refs.c`.  It seems like there should be.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, there are *five* `e058` *objects*, but two of them are blobs and one is a tree:

```
$ git rev-list --all --objects | grep '^e058'
e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c
e05881a4577cedca4d7456b3cb1f8bbd6f480df2
e058d184d1c072bd3078fe17ad41f1026f093201 t/t7008-grep-binary.sh
e05827cba5488fb0c45e7055194071e1fda0df13 Documentation
e058ad2324a89ad5e10a80acf947253eac6c41e1 
$ git cat-file -t e058ad2324a89ad5e10a80acf947253eac6c41e1
tree
```

Git's revision parsing code receives "disambiguation information" from the caller, so that if a command, such as `git log`, tends to prefer commits, Git can pick out only those objects that are commits, skipping over potentially-ambiguous non-commit objects.)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand but is very useful information nonetheless. I'd suggest to craft a new, separate question that is answered by this answer and/or to include this in http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/topics (and/or in Git's **own** documentation, for that matter.)

Comment: @das-g: yes, I almost put in my standard "not really an answer, just a comment that's way past the size of a comment" boilerplate at the top (mostly I just forgot!).

Answer (score 2):

An edge-case you may want to consider: the *lack* of character is also illegal for a remote name.

When adding a new remote name with empty string, `git` will print the following error message:

```
 fatal: '' is not a valid remote name\n
```

But only with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018) you will get a proper message when *removing* that remote:

See [commit 5025425](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5025425dffffb4424b746de9209f874ab8b5d179) (13 Sep 2018) by [Shulhan (`shuLhan`)](https://github.com/shuLhan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 00d5f66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00d5f665a031a0e74d6e03f54d5aba547a5b0c14), 24 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `builtin/remote`: quote remote name on error to display empty name

> When removing remote name with empty string as input, `git` shows the empty string without quote:
>
> ```
> fatal: No such remote: \n
> ```
>
> To make these error messages consistent, quote the name of the remote that we tried and failed to find.
>
> ```
> return error(_("No such remote: '%s'"), name);
> ```