# How to pull from a remote name which begin with a dash

Tags: git, git-pull

In git, it is possible to handle a remote name with `-` character star.

For example, we can add a remote which begins with `-`, update it by just using the option `--` in the git command (`--` separate between command option and the remote name).

But it doesn't work on :

```
git pull -- "-myremotename" "master"
```

And, I get this error message :

```
error: unknown switch `y'
usage: git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

I think that `--` option doesn't work in `git pull`, because `pull` is a combination of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, and `--` isn't used when making this 2 commands.

Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: In your `git pull` line you're using triple-dashes (`---`) instead of double-dashes (`--`). Is that only a typo in the post, or did you really make that typo on the command line?

Comment: @sschuberth I'm using double-dashes (`--`), and I get also an error.

Comment: I think your guess is correct. Try fetch and merge manually. If it worked then your guess is probably probably on point

Comment: This would have been easier to fix when `git pull` was still just a shell script. (Though I note you don't mention your Git version.) I'd advise avoiding remote names starting with `-`, in general, though.

Comment: @torek I'm using `v2.8.0` of git on Mac.

Comment: @yacine: Just FYI, anything 2.6.0 or later has it rewritten in C.

Comment: @torek perhaps I should create an issue on the github repository of git.

Comment: The GitHub Git repo is a read-only entity, I'm not sure anyone pays any attention to items filed there. I also doubt you'll get a lot of sympathy :-) as it's really easy just to avoid remotes named `-whatever`.

Comment: If you want to report this as a bug or just discuss it with the Git developers and Git community, it looks like [their mailing list and their IRC channel would be the right place](https://git-scm.com/community) for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea to fix it ?

Prefix the remote name with the word `safe`

```
$ git remote rename {,safe}-myremotename
```

You can then use it again

```
$ git pull safe-myremotename 
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/develop
```

---

As remote names land in the file-system and also are prone to injection as your question shows, please consider the following:

- Use only characters from the [3.282 Portable Filename Character Set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282)

  ```
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . _ -
  ```
- Do not use the dash `-` as first character. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41464862/367456))
- Do not use any of the digits `0-9` and letters `a-f`/`A-F` within the remote name *only* (if the name is longer than three characters). Otherwise a remote name may become refused by `git(1)` in the future of your repository. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41474545/367456))

And additional and more in general:

- Consider to not start names with a digit `0-9`.
- Consider to not start *nor* end names with punctuation, here `.`, `_` or `-`.
- Consider to use only one case, either lower `a-z` *or* upper `A-Z`.
- Consider to keep the remote name as long as needed while as short as possible, not shorter than three letters. Eight characters is normally a good maximum.

---

And thanks for asking. It is exactly as you wrote that `git-pull(1)` allows to specify the remote name after `--` while that in the `git-fetch(1)` invocation by it, the remote name is passed verbatim into the arguments list.

It does not look like an ordinary injection that allows to get ownage of the whole bakery. The only thing that can be injected to `git-fetch(1)` is a *single* parameter by the configured `remote.<name>`.

E.g. with a single remote named `--all` we can send `git-pull(1)` (and, via), `git-fetch(1)` into child recursion. That is fun but also spams `tty`

#### Example

Name of the remote: `--all`

Process tree of `git pull -- --all` (limited to 6 lines):

```
 121540 Ss+  00:00:00 -/bin/sh
 122011 T    00:00:00  \_ git pull -- --all
 122012 T    00:00:00      \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --update-head-ok --all
 122023 T    00:00:00          \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --update-head-ok --all
 122034 T    00:00:00              \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --update-head-ok --all
 122045 T    00:00:00                  \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --update-head-ok --all
```

Does `git-fetch(1)` tricks itself here already? Sort of, but only if `--jobs=1`. With `--jobs=2` or higher than `2`, `git-fetch(2)` does process the option *more* sequentially and not all-over and again and again. But only if there are at least two remotes.

```
 121540 Ss+  00:00:00 -/bin/sh
 127528 T    00:00:00  \_ git fetch --all
 127539 T    00:00:00      \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127550 T    00:00:00          \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127561 T    00:00:00              \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127572 T    00:00:00                  \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127583 T    00:00:00                      \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127594 T    00:00:00                          \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127605 T    00:00:00                              \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
 127616 T    00:00:00                                  \_ /usr/lib/git-core/git fetch --append --no-auto-gc --no-write-commit-graph --all
```

Well, looks like. `git-fetch --all` has no sanity check to detect if it is re-entrant for the same remote name nor seems to have an option with its own argument to denote the remote (either by name or URL) which could prevent that.

(git version 2.25.1)

Comment: additional referecenes: [Which characters are illegal within a branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651867/367456) (for refname reference); [Git 2.24 release notes](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq7e4gyzgt.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/) (Nov 2019) for introducing `--end-of-options` (is necessary on some git commands using the commonly known end of options delimiter `--` between _revs_ and _pathspec_)