# is there a gitlab cicd IN operator?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, cicd

In the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) I find many `OR` examples:

```
job:
  script: echo "This job does NOT create double pipelines!"
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH  == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop") && $MY_VARIABLE
```

Is there a way to do something like this pseudo code:

```
job:
  script: echo "This job does NOT create double pipelines!"
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in ($CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH, "develop") && $MY_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `in` is not an available operator. However, regex offers an equivalent with patterns like `(a | b)` so `$FOO in (a, b)` could be expressed with a regex rule like `$FOO =~ /(a | b)/`

So something like this might work for you:

```yaml
# ...
variables:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /(main|develop)/ && $MYVAR'
```

One caveat, however, is that because of [unresolved issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209904) in GitLab's regex and variable handling, you can't use variables directly in a pattern. So you have to statically declare your default branch as above in this case.

In cases where you must use a variable, your first example is probably the most reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: **tested not working** (kept for reference of discussion, to be removed later)

---

I came to [a similar conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76342377/367456) like [sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747944/sytech) to use a [**regular expression**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern), and also considered similar to Gitlabs remark with the variables as this is a common problem.

Therefore I checked with the regular expression specification in use and consider the problem greatly reduced thanks to `\Q...\E` support in RE2[¹](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax):

```
job:
  script: echo "This job does NOT create double pipelines!"
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^(\Q$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH\E|develop)$/ && $MY_VARIABLE
```

This syntax allows to use branch names that contain slashes `/` as well, e.g. `fix/me/later` (not that I want to promote them, this is just a pretty silly example).

If you follow branch naming rules in git[²](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72383150/367456), you should not run into this kind of problem anyway.

Comment: Does this actually work? My understanding is the problem in GitLab is more about the variable interpolation/expansion behavior. GitLab won't expand variables inside of the re expression so only `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` and `MY_VARIABLE` get expanded, so the expression comes out something like `branchname =~ /^(\Q$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH\E|develop)$/ && variable_value` after interpolation -- that is `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` is never understood to be the value of this predefined variable. But maybe my understanding there is not correct.

Comment: Isn't the interpolation on word boundaries? As the variable name is properly terminated with a symbol (and starts with the `$`) I was under the impression this must work, but now as you comment on it I should run a test-case... @sytech

Comment: @sytech: you're right, I stand corrected, it does not work. unfortunately. Wondering a bit why the substitution / expansion is that limited, but nevertheless, doesn't work.